# Redis OOM trying to force error

Tags: caching, redis

We were getting the error:

```
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory
```

and now I am trying to rebuild the error on my local system, but sadly failing :|

redis-cli info gives me this:

```
maxmemory_human:10.00M
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
```

and I am forcing the cache to be overflooded - but it always stays around 10MB

```
used_memory_human:10.01M
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Your mistake is not reading about the eviction policies - you're basically telling redis to throw the OOM error when it reaches the 10M mark, which is exactly what it is doing. What are **you** trying to do, is perhaps, the more important question to answer.

Comment: Actually it is NOT doing it - that is my question here. In Live it throws the exception - on my local system it DOES NOT. Same maxmemory_policy : noeviction

Comment: Have you set `maxmemory` in your local? Are you trying to actually add a new (synthetically big) value? Are your keys set to expire?